# Fetch data from serverPrefetch() to mounted()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, server-side-rendering

Question by topic: [Data Pre-Fetching and State](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/data.html#data-store)

I want to accept data from the server-side in order to use it on the client-side.

```
export default {
    // ...
    serverPrefetch () {
        this.$store.device = this.$vnode.ssrContext.device

        console.log(this.$store.device) // desktop
    },

    mounted () {
        console.log(this.$store.device) // undefined
    }
    // ...
}
```

Tried using the store but doesn't work. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: why dont you just use nuxt

Comment: @ifaruki For some reason, you need to solve this problem without using a Nuxt... What can you advise? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't assign the variable of device directly. Try use actions or mutations